# Does Vorpal Spikes proc Rylai's crystal scepter slow?

Tags: league-of-legends

[Some people say it does](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1956091), and [some people say it doesn't](http://www.gamespot.com/league-of-legends/forum/rylais-is-amazing-on-chogath-56041576/).

My friend is pretty sure [Cho'Gath's Vorpal Spikes](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Cho%27Gath/Ability_Details) does proc [Rylai's Crystal Scepter](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Rylai%27s_Crystal_Scepter)'s passive, but we both can't test at the moment.  I thought it didn't proc on toggle skills, but he swears it does.  The people in the threads I mentioned seem to classify Vorpal Spikes as an AoE spell rather than an on-hit toggle skill...  Anyone have some insight on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm thinking it does add the slow from Rylai's. I've been looking on the wiki's and I found this:

> The following will not trigger a slow:
>
> - Champion abilities that do not trigger spell vamp
> - On-hit damage damage dealt by items
> - Summoner Spells, such as  Ignite and  Smite.
> - Damage dealt by the auto-attacks of Clones and Pets/Minions.

[http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Rylai's_Crystal_Scepter](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Rylai%27s_Crystal_Scepter)

Then on this page http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/On-hit_effect#Items I found under:

Abilities — do apply spell vamp:

> Area Of Effect
>   The following effects deal area of effect damage, but
>   are not classified as splash damage:  Cho'Gath's  Vorpal Spikes

Comment: Good finds. Nice to have this info readily available on the exchange

Comment: I think it is safe to say that it will trigger the 15% slow and not the 35%

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not a spell. It is a passive effect, kind of like Teemo's Toxic Shot, which does not proc slow with Rylai's Crystal Scepter.

Comment: Sorry dude, I have to -1 this because you are wrong. :(